# Hibernate one-to-many lazy loading with hbm

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have couple of classes, `Student` and `Address`. To get one to many relation, let's say that one student can have many addresses. I created .hbm files for this structure, but I want to load addresses for a student lazily. But it is always loading addresses in student object. I can see a couple queries getting fired. Like fetching info from Student table and Address table.

`lazy=true` or `lazy=false` doesn't have any effect and 2 queries are always fired (student and address).

Student.hbm:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernate.s4.Student" table="STUDENT">

<id name="studentId" column="stdid">
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>

<property name="studentName" column="stdname" length="10"/>
<property name="phoneno" column="phno" length="10"/>
<property name="degree" column="degree" length="10"/>

<set name="addresses" cascade="save-update" lazy="false">
    <key column="studentId"></key>
    <one-to-many class="hibernate.s4.Address"/>
</set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Address.hbm:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernate.s4.Address" table="ADDRESS">

<id name="addressid" column="addrid">
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>

<property name="location" column="location" length="10"/>
<property name="area" column="area" length="10"/>
<property name="pin" column="pin" length="6"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

client class to save data and fetch student object:

```java
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Student std1 = new Student();
std1.setStudentName("balaji");
std1.setDegree("MCA");
std1.setPhoneno("XXX777CXCC");
session.save(std1);

Address adr1 = new Address();
adr1.setArea("chirala");
adr1.setLocation("AP");
adr1.setPin(523155);
adr1.setStudent(std1);
Address adr3 = new Address();
adr3.setArea("pune");
adr3.setLocation("MH");
adr3.setPin(411028);
adr3.setStudent(std1);
std1.getAddresses().add(adr1);
std1.getAddresses().add(adr3);


System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
tx.commit();

Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where studentId = :studentId");
query.setParameter("studentId", 1);
List list = query.list();
Student student = (Student)list.get(0);
System.out.println((student.getAddresses() != null ? student.getAddresses().size() : 0 ));
```

Comment: `student.getAddresses()` won't be null because Hibernate uses a proxy object even for non-fetched collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code on the println at the end: `System.out.println((student.getAddresses() != null ? student.getAddresses().size() : 0 ));`

`student.getAddresses()` won't ever be null because Hibernate uses a proxy object for non-fetched collections. Also calling `.size()` on your child collection will make hibernate initialize the collection at that point. So it's not null to begin with and by calling `.size()` you're forcing the collection to be initialized.

Quote from Java [Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)

> A proxy is initialized if you call any method that is not the identifier getter method, a collection is initialized if you start iterating through its elements or if you call any of the collection-management operations, such as size() and contains()

You can try setting addresses to `lazy="extra"` so that when you call `.size()` it will only fetch the collection size(ie `select count(*) from addresses`), not the whole collection itself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It helped me to resolve the issue. I have another question. In case if we have defauly-lazy at class level and want to use lazy for another entity with in the class, having equals() and hashcode() would give any impact? example: class Student will have default-lazy=true/false and Address is an entity should have lazy=true (existing with in Student class). In this case having overriden methods (in Address class) hashcode() and eqauls() would give any impact ?

Comment: @BalajiG Yes there is definitely some impact. It centers around what you consider `equals` to mean based on your business logic. There's some pretty good documentation on the topic in the Hibernate docs here: [Link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode)